# Simple Facebook issue: How to get invited friends' IDs with facebook connect for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-app-requests

So my challenge is getting the facebook IDs of friends I invite to my app via the facebook SDK for iOS.

I guess this is done in the dialogCompleteWithURL:NSURL method - but how?

Any help is greatly appreciated as always.

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

And of course, as usual, fatigue obscured the oh so simple answer to this problem.
Just loop through the url that is passed to the dialogCompleteWithURL method and collect the IDs that way.